# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'cloud18i_dbpethu.sessions' doesn't exist

Tags: laravel-8

Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'cloud18i_dbpethu.sessions' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `sessions` where `id` = qsRvWKYASahEiKfVp2UthleTtvxkEZlkb6rronAO limit 1)

Answer (score 22):

The session table is not generated by default when you setup your application, somebody didn't use the session on database (using redis or filesystem)

To generate the table try calling the `php artisan session:table` then, migrate the table `php artisan migrate` this will create a session table for you.

Comment: Thanks Michael fo this solution, this works on Laravel 9

Answer (score 14):

After deciding to revert a Laravel Jetstream installation, a line in my `.env` file was changed from:

`SESSION_DRIVER=file` to `SESSION_DRIVER=database`

Changing it back to `SESSION_DRIVER=file` fixed the issue.

Comment: Not's not a great answer assuming the OP wants to use the database, not the filesystem.

Comment: @ErikvanZijst The question does imply that they want to use the database but doesn't say that explicitly, so I've answered based upon my own experience with the issue

Comment: I am using redis. So mine was commented in the .env file # SESSION_DRIVER=redis I uncommented it and problem solved

Comment: That's exactly what happened in my case. I had a branch to try out jetstream. When switching back to my dev branch I had this error. Of course since the .env file is not under version control :)